# How do I access the current order id in opencart?

Tags: opencart

How do I access the current order id in opencart and put it in a variable? I am working in a new file, which did not come with the standard opencart install.

The closest I have been able to get is the following code, which doesn't work:

```
<?php
session_start();
$order_id = $this->session->data['order_id'];
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order ID isn't set until the customer gets to the final page of the checkout process, so you won't be able to get it before that. For your code above, you can't use `$this->session->data['order_id']` unless you are in an opencart class, therefore you would need to use `$_SESSION['order_id']`

Comment: thanks Jay, that works fine from the final page of the checkout, as you say. I was hoping to access the order id from an earlier point in the checkout process, but it seems that is impossible.

Comment: It is, as the order ID is non-existant until the last step

Comment: @JayGilford i have a question related this post, how can i get last order id to success page.? because i have to set a link to order history info page from checkout success page... thanks in advance